# Importing 16-bit data into Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, nodata

I am trying to import 16-bit data into Google Earth Engine.

I get this error.

> No data value 65536.0 cannot be applied to band #0 of type Integer<0,
>   65535>.

No Data is 65536

I tell it that 65536 is no data here

[image: Where I enter the nodata value]

Comment: what I understand is that `uint16` data can take values from 0 to 65535, so there cannot be a value of 65536, but you are telling it that `no data` is that value (which is out of range). I guess generally the value 0 is assigned to be `no data`

Comment: 65536 cannot be represented as a 16-bit integer (it overflows to zero). The error says the value is not legal.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @clifgray So I used GDAL to change the nodata value from 65536 to something else (think I used 10,000 as this is not in my data) and then on the upload to GEE I told it 10,000 was NoData and it worked a treat

Comment: how did you use gdal for that?